# Computing inverse of a Tensor using tf.map_fn

Tags: python, tensorflow, lambda, map-function, inverse

Using Tensorflow 1.4 I want to compute elementwise inverse (x --> 1/x) of a tensor using map functions. If the value of an element in the Tensor is zero, I want to have zero output.

As an example for the `tensor: [[0, 1, 0], [0.5, 0.5, 0.3]]`, I want to have the `output: [[0,1,0], [2, 2, 3.333]]`.
I know that I can easily get the desired output using tf.math.reciprocal_no_nan() in `tf2.0` and `tf.math.divide_no_nan()` in `tf 1.4`, but I am wondering why the following code does not work:

```
tensor = tf.constant([[0, 1, 0], [0.5, 0.5, 0.3]], tf.float32)
tensor_inverse = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.cond(tf.math.not_equal(x, 0.0), lambda x: 1/x, lambda: 0) , tensor)
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: try reading through this related question which raises a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

Let us break down your code example:

First function you are using is `map_fn`. `Map_fn` will split the tensor across the first dimension and pass those individual tensors to it's internal supplied function. This function is not causing any problem for you.
Next is `tf.cond`. `tf.cond` expects a scalar value in it's predicate. To break down:

```
tensor = tf.constant([[0, 1, 0], [0.5, 0.5, 0.3]], tf.float32)
cond_val1 = tf.math.not_equal(tensor, 0.0)
print(cond_val1.shape)  # Shape (2, 3)
```

`cond_val1` in above example is clearly a tensor. You will have to make use of `tf.reduce_all` or `tf.reduce_any` to convert it into a scalar. Then you will be getting a scalar as required for `tf.cond`. For ex:

```
cond_val2 = tf.reduce_all(tf.math.not_equal(tensor, 0.0))
print(cond_val2.shape)  # Shape ()
```

Now this will make `tf.cond` work. But there is another problem you are getting. You have already lost your ability to process the tensor element-wise.

Secondly, by means of `map_fn` you are passing the entire tensor split at first dimension which in your case will be `[0, 1, 0]` and `[0.5, 0.5, 0.3]`. But the problem is your `tf.cond`'s `true_fn` and `false_fn` don't have ability to process it element-wise.

Hope you got to know the variety of problems which are present in your code.